# Testing docker image. Easy start with exec and get log

Tags: docker, kotlin, junit5, testcontainers

I create small app for my CI. This app very easy, it print to console property, which i set as option, and exit.
I can execute it in my cmd(i use windows), like this:

`docker run --rm myImage:latest say --param "hello world"`

and i see in cmd "hello world".
Now i wand write test on my image. I use Kotlin as main languge, Junit5 as test framework and com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClient as Docker client.  I want write simple test like this:

```
@Testcontainers
class Test{

  val dockerImageId = System.getProperty("dockerImageId ")
  var dockerClient = DockerClientFactory.instance().client()

  @Test
    fun init() {
        val log = dockerClient.stratContainerFromImageId(dockerImageId).withExec("say --param \"hello world\"").getLog()
        assertEqals("hello world", log)
    }
}
```

After bad night with DockerClient Documentation, i can start image like this:

```
dockerClient.startContainerCmd(dockerClient.createContainerCmd(dockerId).exec().id).exec()
```

But wen i open LogContainerCmd and start learning ResultCallback i wanna die!

I'm looking for EASY way, for my simple test. How now it?

Comment: why you would want to do this?

Comment: i wanna test my image. Now i have Unit test on code. But i want now, that my image sacsesful build and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create a container as a test class field as suggested in docs?
https://www.testcontainers.org/quickstart/junit_5_quickstart/ starting from section 2

Then you can run a command, and either do `execResult.getStdout()` or `container.getLogs()`

Comment: It was close! i create 
`@Container
    var myImage = GenericContainer<Nothing>(DockerImageName.parse("myName")).apply {
        withCreateContainerCmdModifier {
            it.withCmd("say --param \"hello world\"")
        }
    }`
and my test
`@Test
    fun log(){
        println("containerId: ${myImage.containerId}")
        println("logs: ${myImage.logs}")
        println("containerId: ${myImage.containerId}")
    }`
but console is
`containerId: cc5e818...
logs: 
containerId: cc5e818...`

Comment: log in test is empty! but i see logs in my docker dashbord.

Comment: it's my fault. Container need time to execute command. i insert Thread.sleep(1000) and i see log!!!!